# OOP PHP classes

Tags: php, class, variables

Let's say I have a class in php, and it includes some functions.

The class is named `something`.

When I load the file on another file, I noticed it goes like:

```
include("the_file_with_the_class.php");
$something = new something(true);
```

now I can do OOP, I know, like `$something->the_function`, but what is that `(true)` in the variable? That really confused me a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the example you gave:

```
$something = new something(true);
```

The `true` is a parameter being passed into the class constructor method.

If you're in PHP5, the constructor method will be named `function __constructor()`. It works just like any other function in that you can specify parameters for it, and these are passed in when you construct an object using `new`, as per your example.

So in your example, the class would have a parameter which (presumably) expects a boolean value and does something different when the object is initialised based on the value of that parameter.

Answer (score 2):

It's a [constructor parameter.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php)

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, `true` is an argument to `something`'s class constructor.

Answer (score 0):

It's an argument that is passed to the constructor

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

Answer (score 0):

The `true` is a parameter that gets passed to the [constructor](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) of that class.
The constructor is a "magic method" that is called upon - as the name says - construction of the object.

```
class myclass
 {
  function __construct($sunnyDay)
   {
    if ($sunnyDay) echo "It's a sunny day!";
   }
  }


  if ($temperature > 20)
   $myclass = new myclass(true); // Outputs "It's a sunny day"
```